# Can't find thinking sphinx log file in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I can't seem to be able to get the log files for thinking sphinx in my rails app. 
My dev environment (she's an old one):

```
Windows 7
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3
ThinkingSphinx 1.3.20 (installed as plugin under /vendor)
```

My sphinx config file for rails looks like this:

```
development:
  morphology: stem_en
  html_strip: true
  bin_path: 'C:/Ruby187/sphinx/bin'
  searchd_log_file: 'C:/my/app/path/log/searchd.log'
  query_log_file: 'C:/my/app/path/log/query.log'
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 2
```

However none of the log files get created. They're nowhere in my Rails app folder, nor in the sphinx folder. Somehow i get the `searchd.development.pid` file with the process id (under RAILS_ROOT/log), and when running queries my Rails development.log shows

```
`[4;32;1mSphinx[0m[0mQuerying: 'major'`
`[4;32;1mSphinx (0.005000s)[0m[0mFound 4 results[0m`
```

The search starts/indexes and works totally fine otherwise.

Comment: Are the log paths you've set showing up in the generated `config/development.sphinx.conf` file?

Comment: yep. `searchd
{
  listen = 127.0.0.1:9312
  log = c:/my/app/path/log/searchd.log
  query_log = c:/my/app/path/log/searchd.query.log
  pid_file = c:/my/app/path/log/searchd.development.pid
}` but only the pid_file shows up

Comment: Not sure what the cause is then... but have tagged this question with sphinx, just in case any Sphinx and Windows experts can chime in.